# C++ double sorting data with multiple elements

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures

I have multiple data entries that contain the following information:
id_number
name1
date
name2

It is possible to put this into a struct like this:

```
struct entry {
  int id_number;
  string name1;
  int date;
  string name2;
}
```

In my data, I have many such entries and I would like to sort.  First, I want to sort alphabetically based on name1, then sort by date. However, the sort by date is a subset of the alphabetical sort, e.g. if I have two entries with the same name1, I then want to order those entries by date.  Furthermore, when I sort, I want the elements of the entry to remain together, so all four values go together.

My questions are the following:

1)  What type of data structure should I use to hold this data so I can keep the set of four elements together when I sort any by any one of them?

2)  What is the quickest way to do this sorting (in terms of amount of time to write the code). Ideally, I want to use something like the sort in algorithms.h since it is already built in.

3)  Does STL have some built in data structure that can handle the double sorting I described efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The struct you have is fine, except that you may want to add an overload of `operator<` to do comparison. Here I'm doing the "compare by name, then date" comparison:

```
// Add this as a member function to `entry`.
bool operator<(entry const &other) const {
    if (name1 < other.name1)
        return true;
    if (name1 > other.name1)
        return false;

    // otherwise name1 == other.name1
    // so we now fall through to use the next comparator.

    if (date < other.date)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

[Edit: What's required is called a "strict weak ordering". If you want to get into detail about what the means, and what alternatives are possible, Dave Abrahams wrote quite a detailed post on [C++ Next](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/02/order-i-say/) about it.

In the case above, we start by comparing the name1 fields of the two. If `a<b`, then we immediately return true. Otherwise, we check for `a>b`, and if so we return false. At that point, we've eliminated `a<b` and `a>b`, so we've determined that `a==b`, in which case we test the dates -- if `a<b`, we return true. Otherwise, we return false -- either the dates are equal, or `b>a`, either of which means the test for `a<b` is false. If the sort needs to sort out (no pun intended) which of those is the case, it can call the function again with the arguments swapped. The names will still be equal, so it'll still come down to the dates -- if we get false, the dates are equal. If we get true on the swapped dates, then what started as the second date is actually greater. ]

The `operator<` you define in the structure defines the order that will be used by default. When/if you want you can specify another order for the sorting to use:

```
struct byid { 
    bool operator<(entry const &a, entry const &b) { 
        return a.id_number < b.id_number;
    }
};

std::vector<entry> entries;

// sort by name, then date
std::sort(entries.begin(), entries.end());

// sort by ID
std::sort(entries.begin(), entries.end(), byid());
```

Comment: He needs a stable sort or this won't work. I'll forego making my own answer since it'll be a lot like yours, except with remarks about how std::stable_sort is really very slow and another merge sort implementation would be much better because best and worst case are n log n whereas std::stable_sort is like...n log n^2 or something dumb like that. So, I'd update the answer to address that, mostly. I'll vote you up if you do. Or I'll explain the theory in my own answer...

Comment: @OrgnlDave: not so. You need a stable sort *only* if you sort *separately* on the two fields. I.e., you sort first by date, then separately sort by name, and intend the dates to remain in order. This is doing both comparisons at once, so a single sort (which can be unstable) arranges by both name and date.

Comment: sorry but that comparator won't provide a stable sort

Comment: @OrgnlDave: What's necessary is a strict, weak ordering. Do you believe this doesn't provide that? For discussion, you might want to read [Dave Abrahams' post](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/02/order-i-say/).

Comment: Upon closer inspection of the code path, it looks like this should work. An explanation of why would make it an A+ answer in my book, but it looks right.

Comment: Nix that. Problem is that it'll compare the two names, and it'll be *done.* It won't come back to compare the dates. You'd still need two passes to ensure it compared names and dates.

Comment: @OrgnlDave: Please read the edited-in explanation of how it works (and, if you want to get into more detail, read Dave's post that I linked above).

Comment: Indeed, it seems this will work. My bad. I shouldn't be looking at fine details of sorting in the wee hours of the night. With that said, I have a vehement distaste for using std::sort using std::strings as keys, but that's a personal opinion.

Comment: First off, thanks for the detailed answer and discussion, I learned a couple things I wasn't aware of previously. The overload of operator< is very handy. The logic seems like it should work, I will implement and test this.

Comment: @user788171 If you want to look into it, you can learn a whole lot about programming just by learning aaallll about sorting. There are a few basic things like sorting that really need to be taught and studied in-depth more, IMO, and kudos to you for following the logic instead of just copy-pasting :-P

Comment: `if (b) return true; else return false;`? `return b;` :P

Comment: @GManNickG: You can certainly do that, but I usually prefer to leave it as-is. First, it maintains the same pattern, and second it's easier to extend if you decide to include a third (fourth, etc.) field in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

That data structure right there should work just fine.  What you should do is override the less than operator, then you could just insert them all in a map and they would be sorted.  [Here is more info on the comparison operators for a map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operators/)

Update:  upon farther reflection, I would use a set, and not a map, because there is no need for a value.  But here is proof it still works

Proof this works:

```
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

struct entry {
  int m_id_number;
  string m_name1;
  int m_date;
  string m_name2;

  entry(  int id_number, string name1, int date, string name2) :
      m_id_number(id_number),
      m_name1(name1),
      m_date(date),
      m_name2(name2)
  {

  }

  // Add this as a member function to `entry`.
  bool operator<(entry const &other) const {
      if (m_name1 < other.m_name1)
          return true;
      if (m_name2 < other.m_name2)
          return true;
      if (m_date < other.m_date)
          return true;
      return false;
  }

  string toString() const
  {
      string returnValue;

      stringstream out;
      string dateAsString;

      out << m_date;
      dateAsString = out.str();

      returnValue = m_name1 + " " + m_name2 + " " + dateAsString;

      return returnValue;
  }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string names1[] = {"Dave", "John", "Mark", "Chris", "Todd"};
    string names2[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};

    std::map<entry, int> mymap;
    for(int x = 0; x < 100; ++x)
    {
        mymap.insert(pair<entry, int>(entry(0, names1[x%5], x, names2[x%7]), 0));
    }

    std::map<entry, int>::iterator it = mymap.begin();
    for(; it != mymap.end() ;++it)
    {
        printf("%s\n ", it->first.toString().c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::map is not guaranteed to be a stable sort

Comment: I'm not saying do multiple sorts.  I'm saying do ONE sort where the less than operator weights name first then date.  Why do two sorts when one (slightly more complicated one) will do?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use function object to implement your sorting criteria

suppose that you would like to store the entries in the set

```
//EntrySortCriteria.h
class EntrySortCriteria
{
    bool operator(const entry &e1, const entry &e2) const
    {
         return e1.name1 < e2.name1 || 
                (!(e1.name1 < e2.name1) && e1.date < e2.date))
    }
}

//main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include "EntrySortCriteria.h"

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    set<entry, EntrySortCriteria> entrySet;
    //then you can put entries into this set, 
    //they will be sorted automatically according to your criteria
    //syntax of set:
    //entrySet.insert(newEntry);
    //where newEntry is a object of your entry type    
}
```